# APEX CPU TIME LIMIT exception while no unnecessary loop already removed

Tags: unit-test, trigger

I try to load 200 data and run test class for my trigger.my test class fail due to APEX CPU TIME Limit .I read on static variable but it is work on bulk upload and if I am using Trigger framework that consist many method should i create one static variable to determine each method has run or not?

The trigger is fire onBefore insert

```
 public static void updateOpportunityCampaign (List<Opportunity> newOppList) 
  {

      String strToCompare ='NonSense -';
      for (Opportunity opp :newOppList)
       {
        if(String.isNotBlank(opp.Campaign.Name))
        {
            String campaignName = opp.Campaign.Name ;
            system.debug('@@@ campaignName = '+campaignName);
            if (campaignName.contains(strToCompare))
             {
                opp.CampaignId =null;

            }
        }
      }

  }
```

Here is my test class

```
static testMethod void  testUpdateOpportunityCampaign()
    {   
        Test.startTest();
        List<Account> lstAccount =[Select Name,Id from Account where Name ='Account 1'];

        system.assertEquals(1,lstAccount.size());

        //retrieve campaign
        List<Campaign> lsCampaign = [Select Id,Name from Campaign where Name like 'ABC -%' Limit 200]; 

        system.assertEquals(200,lsCampaign.size());

        List<Opportunity> lsOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();

        //insert Opportunity and tie it with campaign to test insertion.
        for(Integer i=0;i<lsCampaign.size();i++)
        {
            String opoName = 'Opp Campaign '+(i+1);

            if(i <=66)
            {
                Opportunity op = new Opportunity(Name=opoName, CampaignId=lsCampaign[i].Id, StageName='Create',
                                                 CloseDate=Date.TODAY(), amount=0,AccountId=lstAccount.get(0).Id); 

                lsOpportunity.add(op);
            }
            else if(i >67 && i <=132)
            {
                Opportunity op = new Opportunity(Name=opoName, CampaignId=lsCampaign[i].Id, StageName='Create',
                                                 CloseDate=Date.TODAY(), amount=0,AccountId=lstAccount.get(0).Id,
                                               );

                lsOpportunity.add(op);

            }
            else {

                Opportunity op = new Opportunity(Name=opoName, CampaignId=lsCampaign[i].Id, StageName='Create',
                                                 CloseDate=Date.TODAY(), amount=0,AccountId=lstAccount.get(0).Id,
                                               );

                lsOpportunity.add(op);
            }

        }

        system.debug('@@@@ lsOpportunity '+ lsOpportunity.size());

        insert lsOpportunity;

        List<Opportunity> listInsertedOpp =[select Id ,Name from Opportunity where Name like 'Opp Campaign%'];

        system.assertEquals(true,listInsertedOpp.size()>0);

        listInsertedOpp =[select Id ,Name from Opportunity where Name like 'Opp Campaign%' and CampaignId != null];

        system.assertEquals(0,listInsertedOpp.size());

        Test.stopTest();

    }
```

Debug log snippet

```
05:59:35.559 (84559508274)|TESTING_LIMITS
05:59:35.559 (84559508274)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 22 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 404 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 4 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 600 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 24210 out of 10000 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

05:59:35.559 (84559508274)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|rh2|
  Number of SOQL queries: 1 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

05:59:35.559 (84559508274)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

05:59:36.480 (85480988704)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

(rh2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to separate the transaction by placing `Test.startTest` and `Test.stopTest` after creating the data.

Like this way in your test class:

```
//create test data before this
    Test.startTest();

    insert lsOpportunity;

    List<Opportunity> listInsertedOpp =[select Id ,Name from Opportunity where Name like 'Opp Campaign%'];

    system.assertEquals(true,listInsertedOpp.size()>0);

    listInsertedOpp =[select Id ,Name from Opportunity where Name like 'Opp Campaign%' and CampaignId != null];

    system.assertEquals(0,listInsertedOpp.size());

    Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working.=(

Comment: @unidha Not working or you are getting the CPU Timeout??

Comment: I put the code as you mentioned but still throwing CPU exception.

Comment: @unidha Only this code doesn't seem able to throw CPU time out.There is something else in the behind which is consuming the CPU cycles.Investigate your debug log.Paste screenshot if it is possible.

Comment: update with debug log, i investigate rh2, it is Rollup Helper managed package.

Comment: @unidha some suspicious things are the number of SOQLs and DMLs. Although they are not much in numbers but it says there is some other code running.That code could have any complex logic maybe.

Comment: Let me comment all the method and see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41750/discussion-between-unidha-and-mr-frodo).